# How can I used 10k read in firebase when I refresh a document that only contains 10 fields?

Tags: firebase

Recently, I have learned to deploy a website by React using Firebase.

Since yesterday the database returned that the limit is over, something like that.

Today I monitor it on purpose.

After I refresh the data which includes only one document that contains 10 fields,

and it shows that it has used 10k reads.

Appreciate someone can tell me that is the read count on times or data.

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ('**why isn't this code working?**') must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)"

Comment: My first step would be to look for an endless loop somewhere in your code.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the information Frank asked for, and please also respond using @.